# plot_ly mesh3d colors not working properly

Tags: r, plotly

How do you get the colorscale to be appropriate to the numbers? The highest point is at 2000, and should be blue in this case but the higher values are in red which should be for the lower numbers.  An example dataframe and code are below.

```
test <- data.frame(a = c(10,20,15,30,45,40,20,30,25,30,10,40,10,20,15),
                   b = c(5,10,5,15,10,20,20,15,10,5,15,20,5,10,5),
                   c = c(500, 1000,1250, 750,575,200,800,2000,1500,1750,250,750,1000,800,500))
```

```
plot_ly(data = test,
        x = ~a,
        y = ~b,
        z = ~c,
        intensity = seq(0,2000, length = 8),
        colorscale = list(c(0,'rgb(255,0,0)'),
                          c(0.5, 'rgb(0,255,0)'),
                          c(1, 'rgb(0,0,255)')),
        type = 'mesh3d')
```

Ideally, the color scale would be even more specific where 0-500 is red, 501-1000 is orange, 1001-1500 is yellow, and 1501-2000 would be green instead of a scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
plot_ly(data = test,
        x = ~a,
        y = ~b,
        z = ~c,
        intensity = ~c,
        colorscale = list(c(0,'red'),
                          c(0.33,'orange'),
                          c(0.66, 'yellow'),
                          c(1, 'green')),
        type = 'mesh3d')
```

[image]

Comment: why is the top left corner still red? its above 1500 so it shoule be green/yellow, and the bottom right is under 500 but green

Comment: @theofficefan12, Yes it is. As in your script, you have 3 axes. Note that you have not specified which one is the refrence. Put `intensity = ~c` and that will be what you want. I've modified my response.